# Silverlight error message [Arg_VersionString]. Don't know where to begin

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

One of the users of a silverlight app I wrote gets this error message:

> [Arg_VersionString] Arguments: 
>   Debugging resource strings are
>   unavailable. Often the key and
>   arguments provide sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem.
>   See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.50524.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_VersionString

I checked the log of the asp.net application that is hosting the silverlight plugin and I see no exceptions. The services seem to be working properly, I even witness the trace of this user running the app, and I can confirm that the service successfully returned data.

Something must be happening on the client side, but I don't know where to start. The software is in production already, there are no debugging tools on that server other than DbgView and the problem only seems to be occuring for this particular user.

What would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to reduce the size of the Silverlight plugin, The strings of error messages were removed.  So if any unhandled exception gets thrown this is the message you will recieve.

In order to get the full version of the exception the user has to have the Silverlight Developer Runtime and not the client runtime installed.

If you have a record of the data returned to the client, you might try using Fiddler to inject that data into the client running on your machine and see if it fails.  If it does you should get back the full error message.